# Google sheets: How to use the CLEAN function on referencse from a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets in my spreadsheet, I'm trying to get some columns from the first sheet into the second one and clean the data at the same time.
I've tried using:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(CLEAN({sheet1!A:A, sheet1!E:E}))
```

```
{ARRAYFORMULA(CLEAN(android!A:A)), android!E:E}
```

No error is shown, but the data is not cleaned, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: As @player0 mentioned it'd be helpful to have your spreadsheet shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({CLEAN(android!A:A), CLEAN(android!E:E)})
```

or:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE({android!A:A, android!E:E}, "\s", ))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that CLEAN formula together with arrayformula can work only with one column or row.
There are two ways to workaround.

First:
You can put these 2 columns one on another and use CLEAN formula and ARRAYFORMULA.
You should use a semicolon between ranges `{sheet1!A:A ; sheet1!E:E}`

The other method is to use all formulas twice in 2 columns

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(CLEAN(android!A:A)),ARRAYFORMULA(CLEAN(android!E:E))}
```